# Reading shapefile directory in Python?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, pycharm

I am developing tool on ArcGIS ArcMap 10.0 with .NET and Python technology.

In TOPOTORASTER tool , I give a line feature class. the line feature class path something like this:

```
inputOne = "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpA378\tmpA379.gdb\PerpendicularLine"

inPointElevations = inputOne
print os.path.dirname(inputOne)
pathAfterJoin = os.path.join(inputOne)

arcpy.TopoToRaster_3d(inPointElevations,"D:\\Temp\\topo1234")
```

---

but in python IDE (pycharm) I have seen that feature class path is not valid.
feature class path is broken and it becomes like:...C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp    mpA378  mpA379.gdb ....

space is taken tempA378 folder ...

How to efficiently give input feature class path ??

I am trying like :

```
arcpy.TopoToRaster_3d(r'inPointElevations',"D:\\Temp\\topo1234")
```

but not work..

Comment: you missed the r"" in the first path-strings?
inputOne = r"C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpA378\tmpA379.gdb\PerpendicularLine"

Comment: This is a common error in Python path usage. You must either prefix strings with backslahes with "r" or escape backslashes with an additional backslash or use a forward slash instead

Comment: Alternatively you can use `os.path.join` and Python will handle the insertion of forward/backward slashes depending on the OS the code is ececuted on.

Comment: Your question is confusing.  In the title you talk about a "shapefile directory" but in your question body you seem to be using a file geodatabase.  You say "I am developing tool on ArcGIS ArcMap 10.0 with .NET and Python" but make no other reference to .NET, so that statement seems to just be a distraction from any ArcPy/Python issue you may be encountering.  Please take the [tour] to learn how the site works and use the [edit] button to make your question clearer.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have misinterpreted a suggestion offered in a comment.

Instead of:

```
inputOne = "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpA378\tmpA379.gdb\PerpendicularLine"

inPointElevations = inputOne
print os.path.dirname(inputOne)
pathAfterJoin = os.path.join(inputOne)

arcpy.TopoToRaster_3d(inPointElevations,"D:\\Temp\\topo1234")
```

try using:

```
inputOne = r"C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpA378\tmpA379.gdb\PerpendicularLine"

inPointElevations = inputOne
print os.path.dirname(inputOne)
pathAfterJoin = os.path.join(inputOne)

arcpy.TopoToRaster_3d(inPointElevations,"D:\\Temp\\topo1234")
```

and if it does not work then include the exact error message from running exactly this code in your question.